# How does method invoking takes place?

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, method-invocation

I'm new to Java Programming and learning polymorphism.

**__EDIT__**

As per the answers I received from everyone,I have code:

Here I'm typecasting my `Derived` object (`obj`) to `Base` type and then calling `method()`.

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base obj=(Base)new Derived();
        obj.method();
    }   
}

class Base{
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("In Base");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base{
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("In Derived");
    }
}
```

Output I'm getting is: "In Derived".

So after typecasting my object should become of type `Base` referenced by `Base` type.
But it's not happening? Why?

Does typecast work on child->parent conversion or it has no effect here?

Comment: Well, asking _how does compiler comes to know which method is to be called & too from which class?_ is similar to asking _How does a bus driver know how to apply brakes?_

Comment: `obj` reference is of type `Base` class and the `method()` not available in `Base`.

Comment: Note that your method signatures differ. I would guess you are attempting to override the method in the base class. Simply remove the `int a` from the base class method and you should be fine. As it stands, a reference to `Base` does not have a notion of a `method()` method, only a `method(int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Base obj=new Derived();`

In the above statement, the reference part points to type `Base`. This is how the compiler identifies which class to consider. But your code will create an error. Let me explain the structure of the above statement before explaining why will it show an error.

Structure of the above statement:

1. Declaration-The reference part is `Base obj`.
2. Instantiation: The new keyword is a Java operator that creates the object/allocates space in the memory.
3. Initialization: The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which initializes the new object.

Since, `Derived` is a sub-class of `Base`, you are allowed to call the constructor in the `Derived` class. This is how inheritance and polymorphism works.

Okay, Now let us go back to the error part.
The `obj.method()` in your code is looking for a function `method()` in `Base` class but the `method(int a)` function in `Base` class requires an argument of type integer to be passed. So for the code to work, the calling statement has to be something like `obj.method(5)`.This statement works because the calling statement is actually passing 5 to the function.

There is an easy fix for your code:
`Derived obj=new Derived();`

Have you noticed?

- I have relaced the reference to type `Derived`.

Why does that work?

- Because there is `method()` function in your `Derived` class which doesn't require an integer argument.

There is one more amazing fact about inheritance in Java:

> Everything possessed by a super-class is also possessed by the sub-class but the reverse is not true. And yes, the sub-class has the right to redefine any method/function it has inherited from super-class.

The above statement means the following code will work:

```
Derived obj=new Derived();
obj.method(5);
```

You must be wondering-How come this code works even though `method()` in `Derived` requires no argument. In fact, `Derived` has no `method(int a)`.

> Well, the answer to this is the amazing fact I have mentioned above.

Yes, `method(int a)` also belongs to `Derived` since it's a sub-class of `Base`.

But How does the code mentioned below work?

```
Derived obj=new Derived();
obj.method(5);
```

Simple, the JVM looks for the `method(int a)` in class `Derived` and it finds the function since `Derived` has inherited the function from `Base` class.
Remember this too, the sub-class also has a privilege to over-ride a method in super class. This means that you can add `method(int a)` function in class `Derived` which over-rides the original method inherited from `Base`.

How inheritance works?

- When you call `obj.method(5)` in the above code, the JVM first looks for any over-ridden method of the same type in `Derived`. If it does not find any over-ridden method, it moves up in the `inheritance hierarchy chain` to the super class and looks for the same method. But the reverse is not the true.

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Happy Learning!

Comment: Can u please elaborate me more on the edited code in the above Q. I'm a bit confused regarding typecasting?

Answer (score 0):

> how does compiler comes to know which method is to be called & too from which class?

The compiler searches for the method in the class (in this case `Base`) of the object (in this case `obj`). If the method is not found in that class, then it looks for the method in the super class (in this case `Object`). If still not found, it flags an error.

---

> Is it that compiler checks the reference type class & if method to be invoked is not present in reference type class it gives error??

Yes. But, as said before, If the method is not found in that class, then it looks for the method in the super class (in this case `Object`). If still not found, it flags an error.

---

Your `obj.method()` will fail, because `Base` does not have a method with the signature `method()` (it has `method(int)`)

---

If your `obj` was of type `Derived`, then both these case will work:

- `obj.method();` // will call this method from the Derived class
- `obj.method(1);` // will call this method from the Base class

Comment: How, and to what type?

Answer (score 0):

when there are same method names in different classes , the compiler comes to know by:
1-if you are passing any argument , then the type of argument which you are passing will tell the compiler which method to be called
2-if there are two classes , then make the object of that class for which you want to call the method